# Angular application cannot find symbolic link after angular 8 on linux server

Tags: angular

I recently upgraded an Angular 7 application to Angular 8. Tests, build and runs of the application worked perfectly on my windows machine.

During the continuous integration build on a unbuntu, it however fails when trying to run the tests:

Could not list contents of '/etc/atlassian-bamboo-5.9.7/xml-data/build-dir/MyProjectDir/client/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/cacache/node_modules/.bin/rimraf'. Couldn't follow symbolic link.

I tried removing the node_modules, the .bin folder or even cleaning the build repository and pull the code again, but I still get this error.

My CI server has npm 6.13.7 and node 10.16.3.

How to go around the symbolic link issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the node_modules folder and doing a `npm install` solved the issue.

Let's note that I'm using yarn, but yarn installs doesn't work, it needs to be a `npm install`.

If the issue happens in CI and you rely on yarn for most tasks, run `npm install` before yarn does anything.